# difference between azure virtual machine and Windows virtual desktop

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set, iaas

can anyone brief me about difference between both? Points that I am expecting in answers

1. can we install Software
2. Who is the owner
3. Can I access my local files and software into cloud machine?

any addons from your side will be more than helpful!

Comment: With VMs you are responsible for scaling, network management and etc.
VDI takes all this to Azure, you just have to provide image. With VDI we talking about sessions, but not VM.

1. You can install software for both, VM and VDI

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Virtual Machine**

> An **Azure VM** gives you the flexibility of virtualization without having
> to buy and maintain the physical hardware that runs it. However, you
> still need to maintain the VM by performing tasks, such as
> configuring, patching, and installing the software that runs on it.

- We can ***install the applications in Azure VM***. Use `Set-AzVMExtension` in PowerShell to install the Custom Script Extension.

To know more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Tutorial - Install applications on a Windows VM in Azure - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-automate-vm-deployment).

- By default, the users who created the VM with ***Owner or Contributor roles*** are considered VM owners.

To know more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[VM Owner Detection for Azure (commvault.com)](https://documentation.commvault.com/search/essential/135546_vm_owner_detection_for_azure.html#for-azure).

- It is possible to [access local files](https://directionstraining.com/access-local-resources-in-an-azure-vm/) in Azure VM.

**Azure Windows Virtual Desktop**

> Windows Virtual Desktop (WVD) is an Azure service that, combined with appropriate licenses, services, and resources, delivers a complete
> virtualized multi-user Windows 10 (or a single-user Windows 7)
> experience together with Office 365 ProPlus. WVD includes centralized
> management and monitoring; system administrators can quickly deploy and manage desktops, apps, and Windows servers in the Azure Cloud.

- We can ***install the applications in Azure Windows Virtual Desktop***.

To know more in detail, please **refer** below link:

https://www.rebeladmin.com/2020/07/step-step-guide-publish-applications-using-windows-virtual-desktop-spring-2020-release/

- Azure Windows Virtual Desktop [doesn't have a specific Owner role.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/rbac) You can use the general Owner role for the service objects.